# Como retirar N palavras depois de um match R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Olá, tenho um objeto de strings e quero verificar todas as palavras que aparecem junto com a palavra "conselho". Então digamos que eu tenha:

```
x <- c("o conselho de saúde é muito importante", 
       "a votação para o conselho estadual de segurança foi apertada", 
       "o conselho municipal de assistência social foi instituído em 1990)
```

Eu gostaria de criar um novo objetocom a palavra conselho mais as três palavras seguintes, então o resultado seria:

```
# "conselho de saúde é" ;  "conselho estadual de segurança" ; "conselho municipal de assistência"
```

Eu não estou tendo sucesso com a regex. O que eu tentei:

```
stringr::str_extract("blabla conselho Regional de Medicina blabla", "(\bconselho\b\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,3})")

#OUTPUT:
#Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(\bconselho\b\s"
```

Tentativa 2:

```
str_extract("blabla conselho Regional de Medicina blabla", "(\bconselho\b[[:space:]]*(?:[[:space:]]+\b[[:space:]]*){0,3})")

#OUTPUT.
[1] NA
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a montar a regex correta? Obrigada =)

Comment: Também tentei : str_extract("blabla conselho Regional de Medicina blabla", "(\\bconselho\\b\\s*(?:\\s+\\b\\s*){0,3})") , e o output foi apenas a palavra "conselho"

Comment: Dentro de strings, o caractere ``\`` deve ser escrito como ``\\``. Aí funciona: https://ideone.com/T1cEB6

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta forma é mais eficiente:

```
library(stringr)
c("o conselho de saúde é muito importante", 
       "a votação para o conselho estadual de segurança foi apertada", 
       "o conselho municipal de assistência social foi instituído em 1990") |>
   str_extract("conselho\\X+") |>
 word(1,4)
```

Comment: Acredito que é word(1,4)

Answer (score 2):

Se fizer questão de usar regex

```
txt=c("o conselho de saúde é muito importante", 
       "a votação para o conselho estadual de segurança foi apertada", 
       "o conselho municipal de assistência social foi instituído em 1990")

stringr::str_extract(txt, "\\bconselho\\b([[:punct:]]?\\s+\\w+){3}")
```

Comment: Esta solução é menos eficiente, pois tem de adicionar muitas exceções. Exemplo, se a palavra tiver hífen  já não funciona.